# python using super() function

Tags: python, inheritance

if a class Employee has name,id,age,gender and another class Organisation which has orgname,employees[].
employees[] has attributes of name,id,age,gender these are attributes of first class how to implement it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are confused. Class `Organisation` would have an attribute perhaps named `employees` which is a `list` of references to `Employee` objects. There is no class-subclass relationship between `Organisation` and `Employee` and hence no use for `super()`. There might be better structures than a `list` to use to hold employees, Perhaps a `dict` whose key is the `id` of the Employee.

Comment: @Booboo, agreed. On Object-oriented terms, this is a has-a relationship between Organisation and Employee, not an is-a relationship. (The Organisation has-a Employee. Not: The Employee is-a Organization.)

Comment: @rajah9 That's right!

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to your question. This is just to give you an idea:

```
class Organisation:

    def __init__(self, orgname):
        self.orgname = orgname
        self.employees = {} # a dictionary

    def add_employee(self, employee):
        id = employee.id
        if id in self.employees:
            raise Exception(f'Employee {id} already exists.')
        self.employees[id] = employee

    def lookup_employee(self, id):
        return self.employees.get(id)

    # other methods


class Employee:

    def __init__(self, id, name, age, gender, organisation):
        self.id = id # must be a unique number or string
        self.name = name
        self.age = age # wouldn't date of birth be better because a person's age changes as time goes on?
        self.gender = gender
        organisation.add_employee(self) # add ourselves to the company

    # and other methods


company = Organisation('ItttyBiity Machine Company')
booboo = Employee(1, 'Booboo', 106, 'N', company)
```